# Does Java provide some sort of Register\"Cookies" for storing of temporary data?

Tags: java, cookies, applet, registry

Does the Java provide some sort of registry- or cookie mechanism where I can store small pieces of data to load next start I start an java application- or applet?

For example the application settings such as last opened file etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java Properties are widely used both as persistence format (file) both in memory. They are also widely supported by tools like IDE, ant, maven, etc.

The class [Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is very simple to use and it has several useful method for your purpose (store, load and store):

```
Properties preferences = new Properties();
preferences.put("color", "red");
preferences.put("style", "bold");
preferences.store(new FileOutputStream("prefs.properties"), "preferences");

// reload the properties
Properties preferences = new Properties();
preferences.load(new FileInputStream("prefs.properties"));
```

A Java .properties file looks like:

```
# You are reading the ".properties" entry.
! The exclamation mark can also mark text as comments.
website = http://en.wikipedia.org/
language = English
# The backslash below tells the application to continue reading
# the value onto the next line.
message = Welcome to \
          Wikipedia!
# Add spaces to the key
key\ with\ spaces = This is the value that could be looked up with the key "key with spaces".
# Unicode
tab : \u0009
```

Answer (score 8):

See the [Java Preferences API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html).

It allows you to store preferences *per-user* and *per-system*. It'll store preferences in hidden files on Unix/Linux, and use the registry in Windows-based systems (although that's implementation-dependent).

Note: I'm not sure that it'll work with applets (due to security restrictions).

Comment: The same goes for Mac OS as Unix as suppose?